# PHP: rounding a number into 16 decimal digits

Tags: php, floating-point, decimal-point, rounding

Hi I'm trying to rounding a number into the **16 decimal digits** but it only show and doesn't round up till *14 decimal digit*.

Here's my attempt:

```
<?php

$num= 0.16346153846153846;

$round = number_format((float)$num, 17, '.', '');

echo $round * -1;
?>
```

OUTPUT:

**-0.16346153846154**

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

**0.1634615384615385**

I know that **float** is only 14 decimal digits. Is there any other way around for the **16 decimal digits**?

Comment: Floats are imprecise. As you can see, the last five digits are already rounding errors. Look into [arbitrary precision math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) if that's an actual requirement.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set this parameters at run-time. 16 digits is usually the maximum
value on most platforms, larger values giving only meaningless or "fictional"
digits:

```
ini_set("precision", "16");
```

See [Changing precision level floating-point variables](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/759136-changing-precision-level-floating-point-variables)

Comment: i tried this one before it always gives me a minimum 16 decimal number but if it larger to 16 it also includes 17 decimal numbers on my list.

Answer (score 1):

Recently we experienced an issue with the reading of amount(decimal number) from an excel file which has a decimal number with more than 14 digits after the decimal. The issue is fixed after using the option of an advanced algorithm for converting the decimal number. For this, we need to set,

ini_set('precision', -1);

Ref: http://php.net/precision

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing this, & see what happens?  (May not be the best way of dealing with floats and numbers though)

```
$num = 0.16346153846153846;
$new_num = $num * -1;
echo number_format((float)$new_num, 17);
```

Multiply first, then try rounding the result.

Answer (score 0):

`number_format` and the `precision` INI setting uses `float`, which is likely to result in unexpected behaviour if you're rounding to that many decimal digits.

You can alternatively use the [PHP decimal extension](http://php-decimal.io) with `$decimal->toFixed(16)` or `$decimal->round(16)` to achieve this with guaranteed accuracy regardless of your INI.