# PHP - Round more than 14 decimal places

Tags: php

Is it possible to round more than 14 decimal places?

If I do:

```
echo round(1/3, 4); // equals .3333
echo round(1/3, 14); // equals .33333333333333
echo round(1/3, 20); // equals .33333333333333
```

Is it possible to get 20 decimal places in PHP for absolute precision?

Comment: Hi, see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641998/php-rounding-a-number-into-16-decimal-digits

Comment: 20 decimal places is about an infinity away from "absolute precision."

Comment: PHP `round` can handle it but the `float` type is limited to 14

Answer (score 2):

For lots of decimal places, you'd better use [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php) rather than trying to force PHP to do it.

```
$result = bcdiv(1, 3, 20);
```

You can change the precision ini setting, but you won't get the results you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [decimal extension](http://php-decimal.io) with a reasonably high precision like 28, which then supports up to 28 significant digits.

```
$decimal = new Decimal(1, 28) / 3;

echo $decimal->round(28); 

// 0.3333333333333333333333333333
```